# Is every compact smooth Riemannian manifold bilipschitz equivalent to a finite simplicial complex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, triangulations

Let $M$ be a compact smooth Riemannian manifold. Then it admits a triangulation, i.e. a finite simplicial complex $K$ which is homeomorphic to $M$. Any such simplicial complex carries a natural metric - the path metric which concides with the usual metric on each simplex. Can we always choose $K$ so that with this path metric, it is bilipschitz equivalent to $M$ with the metric coming from its Riemannian structure?

Comment: Of course some homeomorphisms are not lipschitz, but the triangulation theorem gives you a *piecewise smooth* triangulation. So it's bilipschitz when restricted to each simplex, you just have to worry about the seams. I'm not sure if that's enough. But the triangulation theorem gives you something even stronger: a PL (piecewise linear) manifold structure on the simplicial complex, ie, the link of every simplex is PL manifold triangulation of the sphere. This is very good for induction. So I claim that every triangulation produced by this theorem is bilipschitz.